# How to stay in visual mode so I can keep tabbing, for example

Tags: vim

I like going into visual mode so that I have nice feedback on what's selected for an action. For example, if I press:

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>

Now I have my selection all set.

And I'd like to do a certain number of tabs -- perhaps 4, 5, or 6 (I cannot tell until I actually do them and things are 'lined up').

However, if I then press:

<kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd>

It tabs by one and then exits visual mode. Is there a way to stay in visual mode when I'm adjusting tabs and such so that I can do something like:

```
>>>>>>>>>> (too far) << (good)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remap `<` and `>` to automatically re-select the last selection with `gv`:

```
vnoremap > >gv
vnoremap < <gv
```

You can also do this for other mappings, as well.

Comment: but then if I'm in normal mode doing `>>` wouldn't work, correct? Also, what does `g` do? I've only seen it for `gg` and `G` commands.

Comment: `>>` always works on the current line @David542 (or a motion with `>[motion]`) so not sure what to do for that? As for `gv`: it reselects the last selection. See `:help gv` if you need to know more.

Comment: Any reason to not suggest `.`?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work well in the visual workflow the OP described @D.BenKnoble? But yeah, it works well if you use `>{motion}`.

Comment: Well, no, not in the visual workflow :) but even after `v{blah}>`, the dot command works as expected (repeatedly indents the same selection).